# How to use "should" in past?

Tags: past-tense, exam-questions

> It **is** not clear from the manual of instructions whether it should **be** signed or not.

If I have to change the above sentence into past tense then can I simple change *is* into *was* like

> It **was** not clear from the manual of instructions whether it should **be** signed or not.

Or do I need to change the clause after *whether* also i.e.

> It **was** not clear from the manual of instructions whether it should **have been** signed or not.

Comment: Usually "instruction manual", not "manual of instructions".

Answer (score 1):

"Whether it should be signed *or not*" is mildly redundant.  "Whether it should be signed" should be enough.

As user3169 points out in his comment, use "instruction manual" not "manual of instructions".

Otherwise, all of your sentences are fine.  You can leave it as "signed" because this is a past participle that acts like an adjective modifying "it".  For example:

> It was a **signed** copy of the author's first novel.

Personally, I prefer "should have been", but that's just a question of style, not grammar.

> It was not clear from the instruction manual whether it **should have been** signed.